# Is there a Function for actors that does the same thing as the function "move component to"? - UE4 Blueprint

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

i need some sort of "move component to" function that does the same thing but for actors. I´ve searched but I found none

[move component to function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0qC0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the root component of the actor and it should move the whole actor. If you wanted to move the actor between two points you could use a lerp

Comment: Thanks, I`ve tried to use lerp with timelines and worked very well.

Comment: @SergioNani can you please explain how you use lerp

Comment: @Akashkv The easiest way to use lerp in UE4 is with a timeline. This is video is nice and straight forward on how you can use it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLy047C8nKo